# Will I ever be locked out of a specific Hunt?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

Will there ever be a time in the game where I will be too far to go back to a lower level Hunt?

I'm afraid if I go too far into the story of the game I will miss out on some of the Hunts I should be doing then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At 12 specific moments of the game, the list of the Centurio clan hunts will change. Here are the 12 moments of the game :

1. After the parade in Rabanastre
2. After Barheim passage
3. After meeting Ba'gamnan in Lhusu mines
4. After fleeing Bhujerba
5. After obtaining Dawn Shard in the Tomb of Raithwall
6. After Eruyt village
7. After Bur-Omisace sanctuary
8. After the battle against Judge Bergan
9. After gaining access to Archades
10. After Draklor laboratory
11. After Balthier's ship becomes available for free travel
12. Once the Bahamut appears

Some of the hunts are urgent (or *Elite Marks*) and will not be available by reading the board. Talking to Montblanc is the only way to start them. Here is the list of these hunts :

- two hunts (Cluckatrice and Rocktoise) are available at point of time 2 only
- two hunts (Orthros and Gil Snapper) are available at point of time 5 only
- two hunts (Antlion and Trickster) are available at point of time 7 only
- one hunt (Carrot) is available at points of time 8 only
- two hunts (Gilgamesh and Belito) are available at points of time 10 only
- one hunt (Behemoth King) is available at point of time 11
- three hunts (Ixion, Yiazmat and Shadowseer) are available at point of time 12

I'm not sure you can miss the three last ones (the next step is the end of the game). You can at least be locked out of the 10 others.